# iterating over a dictionary in for loop not printing anything in python

Tags: python, dictionary

i have a dictionary which stores a command and an index for that command. i basically want to iterate over that index but whenever i want to run through the loop. it's not printing anything.

```
self.proposals = {}
for sn in self.proposals:
        print "in loop"
```

that's how my `self.proposals` looks like. `{1: {u'client': u'0.0', u'req_id': 0, u'op': u'operation0'}}`. How should i modify the for loop so that it executes the print statement?

Comment: You've literally just assigned an empty dictionary to that attribute, and then you're wondering why nothing happens when you iterate over that empty dictionary?

Comment: You’ve defined `self.proposals = {}` in your code above, then claim it’s something else. Which is it?

Comment: How about `self.proposals = {1: {u'client': u'0.0', u'req_id': 0, u'op': u'operation0'}}` ?

Comment: with this the second assignment of `self.proposals`, you will have print statement occurs

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to have a dictionary within in a dictionary?

Dicts are not stored in any order so if you are trying to iterate over each one in an order it might fail.

If you want to iterate over the keys you can do

```
for key in self.proposals.keys():
```

There are other functions to iterate through the items as well etc. I am not sure what you want your print statement to look like.

Comment: No need for `.keys`